# i need feedback on my PDO login function, will there be errors? and how is the structure?

Tags: php

im new to PDO so im trying to figure stuff out

im making a login system

```
function validateLogin($db,$phone,$password)
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT $password FROM reg WHERE phone = :phone ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone',$phone);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row) {     
        if( password_verify($password,$row)==false)
        {
           //password error message
        }   
        else 
           //redirect to another page or whatever
        }
        else
          //phone number not registered error message
```

how is this looking? thank you.

Comment: `SELECT $password` makes no sense...why would you need a variable there? You should know the name of the field which holds the password in advance. And its name is unlikely to be the password value that the user provided.

Comment: Other than that the code is so minimal it's barely worth commenting on. You're using prepared statements and appear to be hashing the passwords so at least you've avoided the basic security mistakes which most of the misguided attempts posted in the PHP tag here seem to make.

Comment: @ADyson oh it's a typo i meant to type password not $password

Comment: In that case there's really nothing much to say about the code. Such as there is, it looks fine.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: I rolled back your inappropriate edit. I case you're wondering, previous versions are still visible in the history anyway... https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68277018/revisions

Comment: @ADyson it wasn't my intention for it be "vandalizing", i thought it's useless for someone to read it so i spared them the pain, and yes i know it's visible in the history, that's what a history is made for.

Answer (score 2):

Just use column name inside your prepared statement and fetch column result from $row to verify value.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT password_column_name FROM reg WHERE phone = :phone");
```